# How should I deal with the use of deprecated features encountered in learning material?

Tags: sfml, education

I'm using SFML & the book I am reading has that snippet of deprecated code.

Specifically, it uses the deprecated enum `Return` value from the keyboard. The newer replacement one is the `Enter` value.

The deprecated works, but I'm uncertain as to whether or not I should stick with the original material as written in the book, or attempt to make corrections & updates as I go.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: If you do not have an exceptionally good reason for using a deprecated feature, do not use it.

Comment: Because the book I am reading has that snippet of code.

Comment: When you don't understand the material of the book well enough to be able to replace a deprecated feature with the new one, then you don't understand it well enough to use it in the real world either. In fact, a good way to learn from examples is to intentionally try to modify them. That way you can verify that your assumptions about how they work are actually true.

Comment: @Philipp Your comment seems like a good candidate for an answer, you're welcome to post it as such.